# Как преобразовать $this->data в $data?

Tags: php

Есть магический метод:

```
public function __get ($name) {
    return $this->data[$name];
}
```

Он возвращает данные в html-шаблон, но возвращает их в виде `$this->var`, а нужно возвращать без указателя `$this`. Пробовал использовать `extract()`, ну ничего я в нем не понял, и у меня ничего не вышло.

Что можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Abcd
{
    ...
    public function getData()
    {
        return $this->data;
    }
    ...
}
```

...

```
extract($abcd->getData());
```